# rollback manually within grails service

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-2.0

I need to perform a transaction rollback manually within a grails service.
Is there any waywithout throwing a RuntimeException? (Using Grails 2.4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using `.withTransaction {}` block. Like:

```
MyDomain.withTransaction { status ->
   ....
   status.setRollbackOnly() //when you want rollback
}
```

`MyDomain` could be any domain class, not necessary domain used in this transaction.

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#programmaticTransactions